# Switch pages in a WPF application - cannot go to the one page

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have make switch pages in WPF application.

```
public static class Switcher
    {
        public static MainWindow pageSwitcher;

        public static void Switch(UserControl newPage)
        {
            pageSwitcher.Navigate(newPage);
        }
    }
```

And everything work good, I can move between pages, but I cannot go to one page (Question page), in only one page (Add). In other page I haven't any problem to go to this page.

In Add class:

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Switcher.Switch(new Question());

        }
```

I get an error:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Application.Question' to
>   'System.Windows.Controls.UserControl'
>   'Application.Switcher.Switch(System.Windows.Controls.UserControl)' has
>   some invalid arguments

From any other page I can go to Question page without any problems. From Add page I can go to any other page without only Question page.

Question class:

```
namespace Application.Pages
{

public partial class Question : UserControl
{
    public Question()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Add_pyt_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Switcher.Switch(new Add());
    }

    private void page1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Switcher.Switch(new Page1());
    }
  }
}
```

And my Page1 class, when Question page run good.

```
public partial class Page1 : UserControl
    {
        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void bt_Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            Switcher.Switch(new Question());
        }
     }
```

Comment: `Application.Question` does not inherit from UserControl. Can you post the class definition of Question?

Comment: @vcsjones Question class inherit from UserControl. I update my post.

Answer (score 1):

It' most likely because your `Question` class is not in fact a `UserControl`. In the other example you are explicitly passing a `UserControl`.

```
public static void Switch(UserControl newPage)
{
     pageSwitcher.Navigate(newPage);
}
```

Verify that the `Question` class inherits from `UserControl`.

```
public class Question : UserControl
{ ... }
```

If you are in fact inheriting from `UserControl`, try casting it appropriately.

```
Switcher.Switch((UserControl)new Question());
```

Comment: I'm inherit UserControl. I pasted Question class.

Comment: Added additional commentary

Comment: casting doesn't work. I still have a error `Cannot convert type 'Application.Question' to 'System.Windows.Controls.UserControl'`

Comment: Problem solved ;) I change page name and now it's work. Probably I have property with the same name and something blocking it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I changed the page name and now it's work. Probably I have property with the same name and this blocking it.